# Stanford Core NLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

can someone tell me the function of this output in eclipse when using Stanford Core NLP?
[IMAGE](http://s24.postimg.org/tx6ahxn45/Immagine.png)

Initializing JollyDayHoliday for sutime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUTime uses the [Jollyday](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jollyday/) library for turing holiday names into dates. This message just says that it is using this library.